# ¿Cómo modificar una variable que uso en el archivo form.py para usarla en un choice?

Tags: django

estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual tengo un entidad que tiene mas de un campo q se relaciona con otra entidad ( es una ficha tecnica la cual tiene a varios trabajadores ) El problema es q no quiero hacer un Many-to-Many y opte por hacerlo a traves de un Choices.

En mi archivo forms.py primero declaro una funcion la cual hace una consulta a la base dato, luego tiene un for en el cual le voy agregando a una lista las opciones q tengo. Y luego retorno la lista con las opciones. Luego creo una clase para un formulario y uso la funcion anterior. Hasta ahi todo bien.

El problema es q cuando inserto o elimino un trabajador ya no se actualiza esa lista, se queda con los valores de la primera vez q se ejecuta el sitio y ya. Para actualizarlo hay q reiniciar el servidor.

Alguien me puede ayudar.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Los choices son estáticos, si quieres añadir, eliminar o editarlos necesitas una relación ManyToMany.

Comment: Ok, entonces tendré q ponerlo como ManyToMany. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías definir un `__init__`, para instanciar y heredar la clase padre, en la clase del form y asignarle esa lista.

```
class entidadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(entidadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Cambias el choice que te interese, llamando a una función propia que te devolverá una lista.
        self.fields['some_field'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_choices_some_field())

        ...


# Función para devolver la lista que deseas que aparezca en tu choice
def get_choices_some_field():
    list = [("", "---------")]
        # Aquí podrías hacer el Queryset que quiseras
        for val, n in Entidad.objects.all().values_list('id', 'nombre'):
            list.append((val, n))
    return list
```

Comment: Tendrías que añadir mas contenido a tu respuesta. Como el razonamiento de tu código. Si solo aplicas el código, el usuario no aprende.